# is there anyway to bake displacement detail to a mesh so you dont have to use the map

Tags: modeling, texture-baking

So I recently sculpted a model in blender and was wondering if there's any way to bake the detail from the sculpt into a displacement map, pose the low poly model then add the detail back to the mesh using the map. I wanna try 3D printing it but it currently only uses a normal map which wouldn't show in a print. unless the only way is to rig and pose the high poly sculpt

Comment: Hello :). You can use the Displacement modifier, and simply apply it. That will turn displacement into real geometry. But why would you do that, when you already have the hi-res model?

Comment: the high res model lags my computer to move it and makes it impossible to do anything practical with it so I was looking for a way to be a little less hard on my pc